# How to build app in ExtJS that works without mouse?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Now I have a ready  web application in ExtJs that looks fine. But I want to change this application to able to work without mouse and instead of mouse use  *up*, *down*, *left* , *right* arrows only and .

Who did something like this create in his/her work with ExtJS?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS 4.2+ does provide accessibility support which you can read more about here  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/guide/accessibility

Have a read through, it shows you how to use Sencha CMD to add accessibility to an existing application later on in the doc

Comment: Thanks I will read it. But one question. I am using Ext.FocusManager to solve working without mouse. But in some cases this approuch doesnt work: for example I cannot put focus to button in panel toolbar. I would like to know your opinion am i on right way?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext JS 5.1, it has keyboard navigation support built in.

Comment: I am working with ExtJS 4.2 . And I found that Ext.FocusManager fits to resolve my problem. Indeed it works, but i cannot do such things: focus on button in the panel, toolbar. It is critical moment to me. How do you think I am on right way?

Comment: The legacy FocusManager was very limited, and it failed badly at what it tried to solve. Of course you can use it if it works for you but don't expect it to work predictably. It just doesn't. We had to rewrite all keyboard interaction and focus management for Ext JS 5.0.1 from scratch so you can take my word for it.